# Kubernetes pod on Google Container Engine continually restarts, is never ready

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to get a ghost blog deployed on GKE, working off of the [persistent disks with WordPress tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk/). I have a working container that runs fine manually on a GKE node:

```
docker run -d --name my-ghost-blog -p 2368:2368 -d us.gcr.io/my_project_id/my-ghost-blog
```

I can also correctly create a pod using the following method from another tutorial:

```
kubectl run ghost --image=us.gcr.io/my_project_id/my-ghost-blog --port=2368
```

When I do that I can curl the blog on the internal IP from within the cluster, and get the following output from `kubectl get pod`:

```
Name:       ghosty-nqgt0
Namespace:      default
Image(s):     us.gcr.io/my_project_id/my-ghost-blog
Node:       very-long-node-name/10.240.51.18
Labels:       run=ghost
Status:       Running
Reason:
Message:
IP:       10.216.0.9
Replication Controllers:  ghost (1/1 replicas created)
Containers:
  ghosty:
    Image:  us.gcr.io/my_project_id/my-ghost-blog
    Limits:
      cpu:    100m
    State:    Running
      Started:    Fri, 04 Sep 2015 12:18:44 -0400
    Ready:    True
    Restart Count:  0
Conditions:
  Type    Status
  Ready   True
Events:
  ...
```

**The problem arises when I instead try to create the pod from a yaml file,** per the Wordpress tutorial. Here's the yaml:

```
metadata:
  name: ghost
  labels:
    name: ghost
spec:
  containers:
    - image: us.gcr.io/my_project_id/my-ghost-blog
      name: ghost
      env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        - name: VIRTUAL_HOST
          value: myghostblog.com
      ports:
        - containerPort: 2368
```

When I run `kubectl create -f ghost.yaml`, the pod is created, but is never ready:

```
> kubectl get pod ghost
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ghost     0/1       Running   11         3m
```

The pod continuously restarts, as confirmed by the output of `kubectl describe pod ghost`:

```
Name:       ghost
Namespace:      default
Image(s):     us.gcr.io/my_project_id/my-ghost-blog
Node:       very-long-node-name/10.240.51.18
Labels:       name=ghost
Status:       Running
Reason:
Message:
IP:       10.216.0.12
Replication Controllers:  <none>
Containers:
  ghost:
    Image:  us.gcr.io/my_project_id/my-ghost-blog
    Limits:
      cpu:    100m
    State:    Running
      Started:    Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:08:20 -0400
    Ready:    False
    Restart Count:  10
Conditions:
  Type    Status
  Ready   False
Events:
  FirstSeen       LastSeen      Count From              SubobjectPath       Reason    Message
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:20 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:20 -0400 1 {scheduler }                      scheduled Successfully assigned ghost to very-long-node-name
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} implicitly required container POD created   Created with docker id dbbc27b4d280
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} implicitly required container POD started   Started with docker id dbbc27b4d280
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} spec.containers{ghost}      created   Created with docker id ceb14ba72929
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} spec.containers{ghost}      started   Started with docker id ceb14ba72929
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:27 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} implicitly required container POD pulled    Pod container image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0" already present on machine
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:30 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:30 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} spec.containers{ghost}      started   Started with docker id 0b8957fe9b61
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:30 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:30 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} spec.containers{ghost}      created   Created with docker id 0b8957fe9b61
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:40 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:40 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} spec.containers{ghost}      created   Created with docker id edaf0df38c01
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:40 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:40 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} spec.containers{ghost}      started   Started with docker id edaf0df38c01
  Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:50 -0400 Fri, 04 Sep 2015 14:03:50 -0400 1 {kubelet very-long-node-name} spec.containers{ghost}      started   Started with docker id d33f5e5a9637
...
```

This cycle of created/started goes on forever, if I don't kill the pod. The only difference from the successful pod is the lack of a replication controller. I don't expect this is the problem because the tutorial mentions nothing about rc.

Why is this happening? How can I create a successful pod from config file? And where would I find more verbose logs about what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

If the same docker image is working via `kubectl run` but not working in a pod, then something is wrong with the pod spec. Compare the full output of the pod as created from spec and as created by rc to see what differs by running `kubectl get pods <name> -o yaml` for both. Shot in the dark: is it possible the env vars specified in the pod spec are causing it to crash on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use different restart Policy in the yaml file?

What you have I believe is equivalent to

```
- restartPolicy: Never
```

no replication controller. You may try to add this line to yaml and set it to Always (and this will provide you with RC), or to OnFailure.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/pod-states.md#restartpolicy

Answer (score 0):

Container logs may be useful, with kubectl logs

Usage:

kubectl logs [-p] POD [-c CONTAINER]

http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs.html